# Update first Laravel collection/array values based on related collection/array values or 0 if not found

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, mapping

I've been trying to get the difference between two collections:

```
$first = [
    "name" => "Test A",
    "scores" => [
        ["name" => "Values", "points" => 9],
        ["name" => "Algebra", "points" => 6],
        ["name" => "Science", "points" => 5],
        ["name" => "Total", "points" => 20]
    ]
];
$second = [
    "name" => "Test A",
    "scores" => [
        ["name" => "Values", "points" => 5],
        ["name" => "Algebra", "points" => 8],
        ["name" => "Total", "points" => 13]
    ]
];
```

My goal is to create a new collection with the missing key and value pairs based on the first collection, retain its values and the missing key will have a value of 0. The output that I want to achieve is:

```
[
    "name" => "Test A",
    "scores" => [
        ["name" => "Values", "points" => 5],
        ["name" => "Algebra", "points" => 8],
        ["name" => "Science", "points" => 0],
        ["name" => "Total", "points" => 13]
    ]
]
```

Using the [diffKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-diffkeys) method:

```
$collection_new = $collection_1['scores']->diffKeys($collection_2['scores']);
dd($collection_new->all());
```

This will result to:

```
{
    "4": {
        "name": "Total",
        "points": 20
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function down below should work, but the 1st array should contain all scores that the 2nd array has.

```
$first['scores'] = mergeScores();

function mergeScores()
{
     return array_map(
         fn ($x) => array_merge($x, getPoint($x['name'])), 
         $first['scores']
     );
}

function getPoint($name)
{
    $score = array_filter($second, fn ($x) => $x['name'] == $name);
    return ['point' => empty($score) ? 0 : $score['score']];
}
```

Comment: This script is riddled with problems.  I don't understand why it was accepted.  I had to change like 8 things just to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first array is assumed to contain all possible encountered names in the second array, simply iterate over the first array, modify the points element by reference, default all values to 0, then create a lookup reference for the points element.

Then loop over the second array and map all of its values to corresponding first array data to overwrite the initial 0 values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SpFMo))

```
foreach ($first['scores'] as ['name' => $name, 'points' => &$points]) {
    $points = 0;
    $refPoints[$name] =& $points;
    
}

foreach ($second['scores'] as ['name' => $name, 'points' => $refPoints[$name]]);

var_export($first);
```